# MITMPROXY make output human readable to file

Tags: python, proxy, log

My system:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Mitmproxy version 3.0.4
Python version 3.5.2
```

I've successfully installed `mitmproxy` from: [docs.mitmproxy.org](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/) on my server. But now I got confused how to save log mitmproxy to file? I try use `mitmdump --mode transparent --showhost -p 9001 -w output_file`

While I open `output_file`, it's not human readable. I read the docs and try scripts from the mitmproxy's Github, but no clue.

Anyone know how to save log mitmproxy to file, but human readable?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`mitmproxy` has `mitmweb` tool which allows to open and inspect log files:

[image]

PS: I am currently using `mitmproxy` 4.0.3

Comment: Hi Tadas and welcome to askubuntu! Is it also possible to save the log files with this tool? Please put more info to your post.